# How to draw a progress bar inside a list widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, list, progress-bar

I want to have a list of items that need to be processed in a `QListWidget`. Similar to Windows Media Player CD import, there should be a progress bar for every item in the list.

Now there seems to be a way to do this by creating a regular progress bar, using `QPixmap::grabWidget()` to save its appearance in a `QPixmap` and then adding this `QPixmap` as Icon to the `QListWidgetItem` via `QListWidgetItem::setIcon()`.
However, this seems to be horribly wacky.

Do you know a more elegant way to achieve a progress bar inside a list widget?

Comment: take a look at the Qt "Torrent Example" project. It places a progress bar widget inside of a table which would work very similarly. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/network-torrent.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each item in a `QListWidget` can be represented by a `QWidget` of your choice, rather than the default rendering (text). You can set this by calling [`QListWidget::setItemWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget). In this case, I'd recommend using [`QProgressBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html) as the rendering widget -- you should get the desired result.

From the documentation of [`QListWidget::setItemWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget):

> This function should only be used to
>   display static content in the place of
>   a list widget item. If you want to
>   display custom dynamic content or
>   implement a custom editor widget, use
>   `QListView` and subclass `QItemDelegate`
>   instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by converting your list widget into a model/view/delegate combo.  Then you can set a delegate on the list view that overrides the paint functions and draws the progress bar wherever you want it.  I don't know how easy it would be to get an actual `QProgressBar` widget into the drawing area, however.

Alternately, you could consider making your own list-widget like container that knows about the progress bars.

Comment: This approach have a big problem: loosing animation in progress bars cause unable to create "bussy" progress bar.